# create photo gallery with controlled time interval by user

Tags: javascript, html

I have read that lesson: 
http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson17.php 
which contains an example: 
http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson17_ex1.html 
but I need to create a photo gallery with possibility to choose time between photos by user, so I want to modified that line of code:

`galleryStarter = setTimeout("startGallery()", 2000);`

to be as user want, so I add:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>   
<input type="button" id="btnSub" value="User gallery"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSub" value="User gallery"/>
```

also:

```
var btnStart = document.getElementById("btnStart");
var btnStop = document.getElementById("btnStop");
var btnSub  = document.getElementById("btnSub");

btnStart.onclick = startGallery;
btnStop.onclick = stopGallery;
btnSub.onclick = userGallery;
```

and:

```
function userGallery()
{
curImage.src = preloadedImgs[counter].src;
counter ++;
if (counter == preloadedImgs.length)
{
counter = 0;
}
var c=document.getElementById("name").value;
galleryStarter = setTimeout("userGallery()", c);
window.alert(c);
isGalleryOn = true;
}
```

but id didn't work.. what is the reason?

Comment: Can you create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/2/

Comment: @ketan                                                                                        http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/2/

Comment: In your fiddle gallery not working.

Comment: @ketan sorry I change in onload() to in body<>, it run and working, ckeck it please:http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/4/

Comment: It's working what is the issue. it will change the time.

Comment: @ketan 
 
jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/4

Comment: Yes that's working. Check alert box when you change speed it will increase/decrease slide show speed.

Comment: @ketan no it is not working, I want to enter time in text and the interval be as I enter for example if I type 5000 in text the interval time between images will be 5 s

Comment: Yes type 500 in text box and click on use gallery and check.

Comment: @ketan ok but if you increase and type 10000 for example it ll never change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you didn't clear previous timer.

```
clearTimeout(galleryStarter);
isGalleryOn = false;
```

Inside `function userGallery()` will solved your issue.

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/6/)

Comment: You solve my problem,I put that your answer is correct but I can't vote because they need 15 reputation and I am new so have only 8 when I have 15 I ll vote u up ... really thank you and I ll now want to create that photo gallery but with ability to drag a new photo to gallery and show it in slideshow .. how can I do that? .. I ll add a new Q.

Comment: Ok np.  Currently i am going. So, i can't now. When i come back i will show it. So, better to create new question. So, any other person can solve before it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275574/make-a-slide-show-photo-gallery-with-possibility-to-drag-and-drop-new-photo