# make a slide show photo gallery with possibility to drag and drop new photo

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a slideshow photo gallery but with ability to drag a new photo to gallery and show it in slideshow

How can I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/images/1.jpg" alt="Photo gallery image" id="photo" />

    <input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Restart gallery" />
    <input type="button" id="btnStop" value="Stop gallery" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#gallery 
{
    width:620px;
    height:378px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
}
```

A full photo gallery is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/7/):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is far too broad.

Can you tell us anything about the backend you're using? (e.g. rails/PHP) If you want the images that you drag into the gallery to be persisted after a page load then you're going to need some kind of back-end system to store the information.

Where you want to be able to drag the images from? (e.g. the internet/your desktop/a list of images on the same page) This will ultimately dictate how to go about solving the problem.

Where the images will be displayed? (e.g. elsewhere on your site/just on the same page) As above, it's possible to build a simple javascript gallery - which allows images to be dragged and dropped from a list of images on the same page - using something like Knockout.js. However, it's likely that this will actually be very useful without some kind of front-end display and data persistence.

**Edit:**

You can certainly achieve this using Knockout.js. Here is a proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jr2rE/555/

It current just uses `span` elements with the image name, but it's a trivial task to replace these with image tags in either section, as required.

**Edit (2):**

Based on your fiddle, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/q40adx7y/

The issue was that you were trying to just append the image to the container (gallery) element but your gallery is dynamically built using a list of images in the 'images' array which are loaded into the 'preloadedImgs' array to be iterated through.

What I've done is to update the drop function to get the 'src' of the dropped element (i.e. the image path) and add this directly to the 'preloadedImgs' array so that it's included in the gallery as it runs.

Comment: if I have a list of images let's say 3 photos "5.jpg 6.jpg 7.jpg" in the same page and I want to drag one of them to the gallery for example I drag 5.jpg and drop it to gallery then the images will be in gallery:1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg and 5.jpg which I have added ...

Comment: is there any simpler solution?? I ll try to make my jsfiddle to show where I have a problem exactly ...

Comment: Without knowing more about your specific issue one can only provide an open-ended solution that will work as you have vaguely described. I think a fiddle would be a good start.

Comment: I modified my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bs7f16oL/7/   now I want to make star or cat or flower appear in gallery after I dropped them

Comment: Yes, Thank you alot, That is what I need .. but why when I drop images it not appear in the arrange I dropped it in? I mean if I drop it after an certain image it shows after another one..